# Хочу метку [одним-словом]

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, метки

Только что [задал вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/416914/177015) о том, как выразить определенный смысл одним словом. Пытался найти соответствующую метку, а её нет. При этом, [вопросов об этом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%20is%3Aq) достаточно много: 317 из 7863 в целом, то есть 4%.

На English Language & Usage такая метка есть и она вторая по популярности: [[single-word-requests]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests). (Кстати, есть еще и [[phrase-requests]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests), и [[idiom-requests]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-requests))

Предлагаю ввести такую и на этом сайте.

В ответах - варианты выбора названия метки или аргументы о том, почему она не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Ввести метку [одним-словом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc)

Краткое описание:

> Обозначает вопросы о том, как выразить определенное значение одним словом.

Полное описание:

> Отмечайте этой меткой вопросы, касающиеся поиска одного слова, выражающего определенное значение. Задвавая такой вопрос, обязательно укажите:
>
> - Требуемое значение
> - Коннотации (дополнительные оттенки смысла)
> - Контекст использования
>
> Примеры вопросов по этой метке:
>
> - ["Та, мимо которой они проходили". Одним словом.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/43223/177015)
> - [Окрасить в пепельный цвет. Одним словом.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/44931/177015)
> - [Одно слово для значения "свернулся в клубок"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/39284/177015)

Answer (score 0):

Предложение интересное, и, как видно, метка успешно используется на других сайтах.
Однако сейчас вопросы, для которых она была бы полезной, задаются редко, и острой необходимости в ней нет. *(Также стоит обратить внимание на результаты голосования: +1 / -2.)*

Comment: Один из минусов можно не считать, у меня тут почти на каждом сообщении по минусу от одного товарища. )

Comment: Вообще, 4% выглядит как вполне достаточное количество. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin :) ну, даже не считая эти два минуса... в общем, будет много подобных вопросов — появится соответствующая метка